# Docker failing to push manifest file to internal registry due to deprecated schema version 1

Tags: image, docker, schema, push, manifest

I am trying to build an image with a base image from our internal Artifactory registry and trying to push it with a new tag. The docker is able to push all the layers except for the manifest file and gives below error:

```
[2020-05-13T15:09:35.749Z] 189c001fc9de: Pushed

[2020-05-13T15:09:35.749Z] d8cc5c933b96: Pushed

[2020-05-13T15:09:36.014Z] b9df44595a52: Pushed

[2020-05-13T15:09:36.599Z] e9edc362b66a: Pushed

[2020-05-13T15:09:36.858Z] unauthorized: Pushing Docker images with manifest v2 schema 1 to this repository is blocked. For more information visit https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Advanced+Topics#AdvancedTopics-DockerManifestV2Schema1Deprecation
```

I am using Docker BuildKit to generate my image and the push is done with `docker push <imagename:tag>` in Jenkins. Our previous version of code was using docker python package and with that, we can still build the image and push it to our internal registry.

I don't know how to change the Manifest `version 2, schema 1` to  `versions,  schema 2` using Docker BuildKit.

Help me, please!